# Extract Coordinates of Characters from pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to extract the coordinates of all characters from PDF file using pdfbox library. I have used the code from tutorialkart. But when I execute the code, the extraction of coordinates starts from 2nd page or sometimes from center of the first page.

I am unable to understand the logic of extracting coordinates in pdfbox library.
Please help me if anyone knows how to extract coordinates from all the pages.

Here is the code used.. and snapshot of output...LINK OF PDF used - **drive.google.com/open?id=1jPVcag8v8KDgWg_ziVO98sSb9qZV777p**

[image: snapshot]

```
public class Coordinates extends PDFTextStripper {

    public Coordinates() throws IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException    {
        PDDocument document = null;
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Amul123\\Desktop\\Axis\\Axis\\A.pdf";
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load( new File(fileName) );
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new Coordinates();
            stripper.setSortByPosition( true );

            stripper.setStartPage( 0 );
            stripper.setEndPage( document.getNumberOfPages() );

            Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            stripper.writeText(document, dummy);
        }
        finally {
            if( document != null ) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
            System.out.println(text.getUnicode()+ " [(X=" + text.getXDirAdj() + ",Y=" +
                    text.getYDirAdj() + ") height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " width=" +
                    text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please link to your PDF.

Comment: Link for Pdf - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jPVcag8v8KDgWg_ziVO98sSb9qZV777p

Comment: Please make the link accessible.

Comment: The link is accessible now - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPVcag8v8KDgWg_ziVO98sSb9qZV777p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The very first output line I get is `C [(X=557.76,Y=127.28003) height=6.99 width=6.9799805]`, which is part of "Customer No". What version are you using? Try removing setStartPage() and setEndPage(). (These are 1-based)

Comment: After removing setStartPage() and setEndPage(), I am still getting the same. Please elaborate your experience regarding logics used in PdfBox for extracting coordinates.

Comment: Today I finally got the answer and it was a simple error in eclipse settings.....We just need to increase the limit of console to get whole output.......But thanks to Tilman Hausherr for suggesting to upgrade the version of pdfbox.....it helps too....

Comment: I did't see your answer two days ago, I saw this because I was closing browser tabs... always add "@name" to ping somobody. Glad to read that you solved it :-) Consider deleting the question or answer it yourself, and add the eclipse table.